# What's the use for assigning template variable to matMenu when passing it to matMenuTriggerFor?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm digging into how Menu is implemented in Angular Material.

[In their example](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview), they assign the template variable `#menu` to `matMenu`

`matMenu` is the `exportAs` in `mat-menu` component

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I'm wondering, wouldn't it be the same if I would remove the assignment and leave the template variable?

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Tested this on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdjykgjdjkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.html) and it does work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would, but it's a convention to use the `exportAs` method, <strike>because you could have multiple directives on one element, and that element itself could be a component. Using the template variable it will be unclear to what this variable should be set to. That's why they introduced the `exportAs`</strike>

So basically, with a simple example as this, you can use the unassigned template variable, but be aware of bugs if further down the line another developer decides to add a directive to the `mat-menu` tag :)

---

So I've done some digging and realized I was wrong, and made some [example stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvhbzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). If you have this template:

```
<div #test1></div>
<hello #test2></hello>
<hello hi #test3></hello>
<hello hi foo #test4></hello>
<div hi #test5></div>
<div hi foo #test6></div>
```

And `hello` is a component, and `hi` and `foo` are directives, the template reference will be:

```
#test1 => HTMLDivElement
#test2 => HelloComponent
#test3 => HelloComponent
#test4 => HelloComponent
#test5 => HTMLDivElement
#test6 => HTMLDivElement
```

So this basically means, if you do not use the assignment on the template variable, it will always choose the element. If this element is a component, you will get the component instance. There is no way to get the directive without using the assignment notation. So there can be no variable conflict like I thought it would happen before.

As a side-note, not entirely related to your question. If you use the `@ViewChild('testx')` on these elements, you will get the same result. With the difference that you do not get the `HTMLElement`, but an `ElementRef` where the `.nativeElement` points to the `HTMLElement`. If you want to access any directive bound to this element, you would need to use the `read` property:

```
@ViewChild('test6', { read: FooDirective })
test6?: FooDirective;
```

---

So bottom line, it's in the angular material world the convention to always use the `exportAs` template assignment, even though this is not necessary for components. But I guess it improves readability and consistency in your code.

Another reason could be, that if you start to unit test the template code, you would need to provide a mock for the component/directive that's referenced by the template ref assignment. This will not give an error if you just use a template variable. So with that, I guess you can better test your template, as it will provide feedback that you have to mock and thus test that implementation

Comment: For example, if we skip #menu="matMenu", an issue can occur when the directive and the target component implements the same interface, right?

Comment: @Reed an issue occurs because angular doesn't know what to assign to the template variable, because it's not specified. It can be the `MatMenu` component, or the other directive assigned to it

Comment: Interesting, maybe you know if this is documented somewhere? Would be cool to read more on it

Comment: @Reed I've updated my answer, or actually, revised :)